# how to create array of objects without dynamic memory allocation

Tags: c++, class, dynamic

I got following code, where 100 objects are created in a loop.

My question is,

- why do I need the use `new` here, because i already know beforehand how much memory i need.
- is there a code which does the same as my example code, without dynamic memory allocation? (and without using std containers such as `vector`) (...class + dynamic momery together is getting confusing)

example code:

```
class Particle {...};
Particle *myParticles[ 100 ];

for( int i = 0; i < 100; i++ )
{   
    myParticles[ i ] = new Particle(x,y);          //x and y are randomized for each loop
}
```

**[UPDATE]:**
`class Particle` does not have a default constructor. Hence `Particle myParticles[ 100 ];` will not work. Note that, there is a work around by setting up a default constructor, and then creating methods `Particle::setXY (double x, double y)`.

But is there a way to solve this without creating new methods?? ie only using constructor, and no dynamic memory allocation.

I just find it strange, that this cannot be done(?) without dynamic memory allocation. Or do I have to accept the fact that this just a quirk of C++ language??

Comment: Show Particle, and what do you want to do with the array.

Comment: No, `[100]` tells you that `myParticles` is an *array*. *Arrays are not pointers.*

Comment: @molbdnilo Ah of course, my bad. Of course it is ARRAY of class POINTERS. That explains that.

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to use `new`. You can create an array of `Particle`s as you suggested yourself:

```
Particle myParticles[100];
```

The thing is, it will be default-constructed as you cannot specify `(x,y)` parameters which are only available at runtime. So you will have to provide means to specify this information after the construction of a `Particle`, for example like this:

```
for( int i = 0; i < 100; i++ )
{   
    myParticles[i].SetCoords(x,y);          //x and y are randomized for each loop
}
```

This requires both default constructor for `Particle` and a method like `SetCoords` to configure the instance after construction. So it might not be an option if the code for `Particle` is beyond your control.

But I would really consider using `vector` as it's a very convenient and useful thing. It will be quite efficient as it uses very little number of dynamic allocations if programmed correctly. For example:

```
vector<Particle> myParticles;

myParticles.reserve(100);
for( int i = 0; i < 100; i++ )
{   
    myParticles.push_back(Particle(x,y));          //x and y are randomized for each loop
}
```

This should use just a single allocation. This assumes that `Particle` is fairly lightweight to be copied by a copy constructor.

Comment: Good, but you are assuming that Particle have a default constructor and a way of setting new "coordenat". We dont know.

Comment: @qPCR4vir, sure the first method requires default c'tor, added this explicitly to the answer now. The second method also has some requirements. If nothing of this is an option, then one has to go with dynamic allocations for every instance as in the original code.

Comment: @unkulunkulu I updated my question. Indeed I imagined a case without default constructor. And as for your second solution, I said no vectors, because is does use dynamic allocation. And I just find it strange that this cannot be done without one, that's why I asked this question.

Answer (score 1):

> **why do I need the use new here, because i already know beforehand how much memory i need?**

The reason is that probably this piece of code exists in a function. Creating an array local to the function and returning pointer/reference to it would result in Undefined behavior. So maybe the reason is to **explicitly manage the lifetime of the created array elements**. There is no way to tell exactly unless you show more code.

> **Is there a code which does the same as my example code, without dynamic memory allocation?**

In general if given a choice,

```
Particle myParticle[100];
```

is much better and less error prone than using dynamic memory allocations.

**Good Read:**
[Why should C++ programmers minimize use of 'new'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6500313/why-should-new-be-used-as-little-as-possible)

Note that while it is good to limit the use of `new` as much as possible, the purpose of existence of `new` is because it is needed for some situations where it is more suited for the behavior desired. So it is more of an horses for courses.

Comment: I don't think that speculation on the reasons are either correct or to the point: I don't see how putting all the pointers in a local array of pointers helps returning this array from the function, at least while looking at the provided example.

Comment: @Alok Save Yes, this code is inside a function. This sidesteps my original question abit but..

..But now im confused: I can create an array inside the function, and surely this array which is local to the function will get destroyed when the function exists, no matter if its dynamically or statically allocated. Or is my understanding false(?)  Also, please see update to my question, and why `Particle myParticle[100];` wouldnt work

Answer (score 1):

```
Particle myParticles[ 100 ];
```

will use the default constructor 100 time and not `Particle(x,y)`

So, the real problem is that you have no way of passing argument to the constructor in the array.

**If `Particle` has not default constructor  `Particle myParticles[ 100 ];` will not compile**

We need more information. It could be that Particle is big, but we want to sort the array. Having an array of pointers you can swap it, and this could be a lot faster than swap Particles. The implementation of swap of Particles could be far from trivial.
Finally you can pass the array calling other functions with make a copy of these pointers... Well complicate.

Comment: Good to point this out, this was the point to my question actually. About constructors. Please see update in my original question.

Answer (score 0):

Being a C programmer that's how I'd roll:

```
char particle_space[sizeof(Particle) * 100];
Particle *myParticles = (Particle *) particle_space;
```

Then fill it the following way:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    myParticles[i] = Particle(i, i);
```

I don't know if using `sizeof` in declaration is portable or if it's gcc's extension but that worked for me.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but I'm having enough difficulty  just with C++ along without involving another language.   O_O

Comment: Nice trick... but who will call the destructor for each element? Supous Particle take some other resourses appart from the memmory.

Comment: Destruct? Why would you need to call destruct on pre-allocated objects? And the particle elements created during array initialization are created on stack, their lifetime is limited to the loop cycle.

Answer (score -1):

```
Particle *myParticles[ 100 ];
```

is array of Particle pointers, not Particles. And myParticles type is Particle** not just Particle*, that is why you need to allocate memory.

```
Particle myParticles[ 100 ];
```

would indeed create an array of Particle and there will be no need in mem allocation.

Comment: -1 for propagating the "arrays are pointers" myth - the type of `myParticles` is *not* `Particle**`.

Comment: I dont know the myth you are referring to here. I also thought array almost equals to pointer..

Comment: There is no almost equal. Array is not a pointer, for example you can't do something like myParticles++. Thus I can't blame downwoters, as strictly saying myParticles is not Particle** indeed.